# How could I calculate with every value from a python mysql database in one go?

Tags: python, mysql

Quick little bit of context: I'm making a discord.py bot (which is irrelevant) so just keep in mind that it has to happen on an command trigger.

I'm trying to have my code go through my database and calculate a set percentage with each value specific value in my database.

For Example:

1. Command Ran
2. Loops through entire database calculating with each value stored under 'money'.
3. Stores the newly calculated value and stores it again.

The concept of looping through it, using the value to calculate an amount and storing it again is the tricky part for me. If anyone has any ideas/suggestions on how to do this please do let me know.

Database has the following stored inside of it:
`data (personID VARCHAR(50), money int, oldmoney int, info TEXT)`

Trying to loop through the money value.

Comment: You haven't said what you're trying to do in the loop, but it's likely you can just put it in the database query. E.g. `SELECT AVG(money) FROM data`

Comment: `UPDATE data SET oldmoney = money * ?` where `?` is the parameter with the percentage.

Comment: "Stores the newly calculated value and stores it again" What does "stores it again" mean? Why do you have to store it twice?